# Is it fine to use 'Product' for the product specification page (without selling)?

Tags: google, schema.org, products

I just want to confirm that I have a webpage where I am displaying mobile phone specification (I am not selling). Is it fine with search engines like Google if I use [Schema.org’s `Product`](http://schema.org/Product) for my webpage?

I am asking this question because my concern is that if I use the `Product` schema, then maybe Google will take my website as an eCommerce website? But I am not selling products, I am just displaying specifications of products.

If you think that another schema will produce better results, then please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Google words for [product schema.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products)

> If you're a merchant, you can give Google detailed product information
>   that we can use to display rich results (for example, price,
>   availability, and review ratings) right on Search results pages.

So, if you're not merchant, I don't recommended to use Product. Instead I recommend that your site uses [Schema.org reviews](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews), which is recommended by Google and it will best fit for your website.